# Help with an exponential function with an indicator and using the EM Algorithm

Tags: exponential-distribution, expectation-maximization

Two bulbs, Brand A and Brand B, in which their lifetimes are distributed exponentially with expectations $\lambda$ and $\mu$ respectively.  They pair $X_i$ and $Y_i$.

In the ith experiment, instead of letting both two bulbs
burn until they die out, they stop when one of the bulbs burn out, and record
the burning time $Z_i$ and indicator $W_i$ of which one burns out.  This is repeated $n$ times.

$Z_i = min(X_i,Y_i)$, and $W_i = \begin{cases} 
\;\;1,\quad if \;Z_i=X_i,\\
\;\;0,\quad if \;Z_i= Y_i.
\end{cases}$

When applying the EM algorithm, I am trying to show that $$\lambda^{(k+1)}=\frac{\sum_i^n w_iz_i+\sum_i^n(1-w_i)(z_i+\lambda^{(k)})}{n}$$ $$\mu^{(k+1)}=\frac{\sum_i^n (1-w_i)z_i+\sum_i^nw_i(z_i+\mu^{(k)})}{n}$$

Here's where I am with my attempt:

I know that $Z_i$ is independent and the joint likelihood function is: $L_n(W,Z,\mu,\lambda)=\lambda^{\sum w_i}\mu^{n-\sum w_i} e^{-(\lambda+\mu)\sum z_i}$
and the log-likehood is:

$l_n=\sum w_i ln(\lambda)+(n-\sum w_i)ln(\mu) - (\lambda+\mu)\sum z_i$

I am stuck on between the E and M step.  Any advice would be appreciated!
Thank you!